# GIT - Rewriting core code on a separate branch

Tags: git

I have this scenario which I do not think is uncommon but I am struggling to find an example of how it is done properly on the net.

We have our project, with a master branch. For my example lets say current state of the master identifies v1.5.0 of the project.

Now we decide to write v2.0.0, to which massive changes and rewrites will happen, files will be completely removed and deleted. This rewrite now takes place on a new branch we shall call **unstable**.

A week or so into development on unstable a feature and/or a bugfix needs to be added to v1.5.0, no problem we say new branch - write feature - merge with the master. The master is now at v1.6.0.

Now, this fix/feature does not apply to the new version of the project as the the entire project is being rewritten.

We complete v2.0.0 on the **unstable** branch which was originally based on v1.5.0 of the **master** branch which is now at say... v1.8.4 - how would you go about merging the unstable branch with the master branch without: destroying the history of versions 1.5 through to 1.8.4 or leaving artefacts from pre 2.0.0 versions in the merged branch and possibly breaking the new code written in v2.0.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably already know `git merge -s ours`, which does exactly the opposite of what you want to do: it ignores the changes in the *source* branch and lets the merge result be exactly identical to the contents of the *target* branch. There is no corresponding `-s theirs`, though, for reasons I'm not going to go into here.

So, we'll have to improvise something that has the same effect. Rough outline: do a merge without committing, magically mangle the 2.0.0 code into it, and then finalize the merge.

First off, make sure you have no uncommitted changes. We're going to be using fun tricks here; warranty void and all that.

1. on master, `git merge -n unstable`. The `-n` will make sure the merge isn't committed yet, even if there are no conflicts (of course you'll get conflicts due to your extensive rewriting, but let's be safe).
2. this is the magic: `git read-tree --reset -u unstable` (read `unstable` into the index and update the working tree accordingly, ignoring any conflicts)
3. `git commit` to finalize the merge. It will now have both old and new in its *history*, but only 2.0.0 stuff in the *tree*.
4. Check that this whole thing left no remnants of your previous master version as untracked files. I don't know for sure whether this can actually happen, but it can't hurt to check.

Comment: Thanks, something new learned every day! I was surprised though that this doesn't happen with more regularity but then it's probably not often you decide to bin such a huge section of code whilst also adding improving the very same code you a doing away with on a different branch.

Comment: @MikeHancock yeah. What people probably do more commonly is that they do all development of the next big version directly on master, and maintenance work on a separate branch. That's the way Git itself is developed, for example. It has `master` for next stable version, `maint` for the old version, `next` for roughly beta-quality stuff meant to graduate to `master`, and `pu` for unstable stuff. Still, if you bring `maint` forward to a new version after releasing a new stable version, you're probably going to end up having to do something like what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about how to handle massive diverging branches. There are a few options here:

- merge: less than ideal since you'll get many conflicts, and if core has changed it'll be difficult to solve and make sure everything work.
- handcraft: inspect the changes made on `master` since `unstable` diverged, and recode them. This is  the case when you realize that divergence between branches is too big, and merging makes no sense. However you can still cherry-pick the commits that still apply. You'd better have some separate issue tracker that lists the things applied on `master` since branch separation.

Note that rebase isn't an option because `master` branch is already published.

On a side note a very interesting project is in beta but looks usable: [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge). This project allows to merge commits one by one, and solve conflicts that a lot smaller.